# Google maps geocode does not give results

Tags: google-maps

7-A Artsan Towers Trichy Road,Ramanathapuram, Coimbatore Tamil Nadu

This is what I have typed in google maps, and it gives me 5 results.

[image]

But when I give the same address in geocode api, it gives me zero results. 
How should I handle this, I would like to have nearest lat long

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=7-A%20Artsan%20Towers%20Trichy%20Road,Ramanathapuram,%20Coimbatore%20Tamil%20Nadu&postal_code=641045&key=keyIsHere
Result is

```
{"results"=>[], "status"=>"ZERO_RESULTS"}
```

Comment: The geocoder is for **postal addresses**.  It doesn't work for "places" (Artsan Towers). For those, use the places API.

Comment: So places api will give long long as I was expecting?

Comment: [Yes, place result for 7-A](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=7-A%20Artsan%20Towers%20Trichy%20Road,Ramanathapuram,%20Coimbatore%20Tamil%20Nadu&place=1)

Answer (score 0):

Here you should avoid flat number, floor numbers and business names.

For more info read [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)

It's worked for me [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=7A,Artsan%20Towers%20Trich%20Road,Ramanathapuram,Coimbatore%20Tamil%20Nadu&postal_code=641045&key=Your_KEY](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=7A,Artsan%20Towers%20Trich%20Road,Ramanathapuram,Coimbatore%20Tamil%20Nadu&postal_code=560045&key=YOUR_KEY)

Result:

```
{   "results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Artsan Towers",
           "short_name" : "Artsan Towers",
           "types" : [ "premise" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "4",
           "short_name" : "4",
           "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Trichy Road",
           "short_name" : "Trichy Rd",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Near Ramanathapuram Signal, Behind SS Palamuthir Nilayam",
           "short_name" : "Near Ramanathapuram Signal, Behind SS Palamuthir Nilayam",
           "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Ramasamy Nagar",
           "short_name" : "Ramasamy Nagar",
           "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_2" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Ramanathapuram",
           "short_name" : "Ramanathapuram",
           "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Coimbatore",
           "short_name" : "Coimbatore",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Coimbatore",
           "short_name" : "Coimbatore",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Tamil Nadu",
           "short_name" : "TN",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "India",
           "short_name" : "IN",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "641045",
           "short_name" : "641045",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Artsan Towers, 4, Trichy Rd, Near Ramanathapuram Signal, Behind SS Palamuthir Nilayam, Ramasamy Nagar, Ramanathapuram, Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu 641045, India",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 10.9974156,
           "lng" : 76.9949293
        },
        "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 10.9987645802915,
              "lng" : 76.99627828029151
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 10.9960666197085,
              "lng" : 76.9935803197085
           }
        }
     },
     "partial_match" : true,
     "place_id" : "ChIJEVWhlsNZqDsR4AxMyrJZQPM",
     "types" : [ "street_address" ]
  }   ],   "status" : "OK"}
```

Comment: can you tell me, what was the problem

Comment: In your request 7-A is considering as flat number or floor number, you should avoid that.